# Writing through serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

below you can see my program output.While my device begin to boot, through serial port I send serialport1.write("\n"); and i topped the autoboot. then I must send three commands with serialport1.write command. if the thread sleeps before the command the commands are executed but i see the result after the commands done. I mean if i get slept the thread 1 sec before the commands, for 3 commands i see the result in richtextbox after 3 seconds. Why? Is there any other good way to executing the commands? my code is below.

THE CODE:

```
_data = _serialPort.ReadExisting();
if (_data.StartsWith("Hit"))
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    _serialPort.Write("\n");
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    _serialPort.Write("set moviargs...\n");
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    _serialPort.Write("saveenv\n");
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    _serialPort.Write("boot\n");
}
```

THE OUTPUT:

> Hit any key to stop autoboot:  3  2  1
>   0
>
> SMDKV210 # set moviargs "setenv
>   bootargs console=ttySAC2,115200
>   smsc95xx.macaddr=00:09:DF:90:00:03"
>
> SMDKV210 # saveenv
>
> Saving Environment to SMDK bootable
>   device...
>
> done
>
> SMDKV210 # boot

Comment: Actually how i can pause and continue my program between commands except using thread.sleep() ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're UI won't update in Thread.Sleep.

Add some Application.DoEvents step before each 'Sleep' call to update the UI. (or run the code talking to the serial port on a background thread)

The Application.DoEvents call should handle 'waiting' events like screenupdate but will also try and start button clicks. You'd have to add a mechanism to disable button clicks(just disable the buttons).